# How to pass multiple dates for Same Parameter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to pass 2 dates as binding variable. But the resultset printing only for the second date. How to pass two dates for the same parameter Holidays

```
Sub Ora_Connection()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Dim i As Integer
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

i = 2
strCon = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=XXXX/YYY;User Id=XXXX;Password=YYYY"

con.Open (strCon)
Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
With Cm
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(DATE_VALUE) FROM PAYOR_DW.DATE_DIMENSION
                    WHERE DATE_VALUE  >= PAYOR_DW1.DATE_VALUE  
                    AND DATE_VALUE  < PAYOR_DW2.DATE_VALUE 
                    AND IS_WEEKDAY = 'Y' 
                    AND INSTR((:Holidays) ,DATE_VALUE,1,1)< 1 )AS 'TURNAROUND TIME'
                    FROM PAYOR_DW.CORRESPONDENCE_FACT CF "
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    Set Pm = .CreateParameter("Holidays", adDate, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append Pm
    Pm.Value = "18-FEB-19"
    Set rs = .Execute
    Pm.Value = "20-FEB-19"
    Set rs = .Execute

End With

While Not rs.EOF
Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value = rs.Fields(1).Value
Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value = rs.Fields(2).Value
Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = rs.Fields(10).Value
Sheet3.Cells(i, 4).Value = rs.Fields(4).Value
i = i + 1
rs.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are executing two commands, but your second `Cm.execute` overwrites the values in your rs. How about using two resultsets, rs1 and rs2? Or, you may process the resultset values and then call another execute.

Comment: I can't use two result-sets because when i pass that value, data in a column decreases by one for that particular date

Comment: You should show your `.CommandText` to see if you're writing it well. Theoretically, it should look something like `.CommandText = "update YOUR_TABLE set YOUR_FIELD where YOUR_DATE not in (@date1, @date2)"` and then `Set Pm1 = .CreateParameter("@date1", adDate, "18-FEB-2019")`, `.Parameters.Append Pm1`, `Set Pm2 = .CreateParameter("@date2", adDate, "20-FEB-2019")`, `.Parameters.Append Pm2`,  to finally execute all at once with `Set rs = .Execute`.

Comment: I updated the Query, where you can see we have only one **:Holidays** parameter